# Is eating in the bedroom forbidden?

Tags: halacha, food, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, eating

Is eating in the bedroom or any typical part of the bedroom forbidden? I've heard that there's some sort of tumah associated with this action, but couldn't get verification outside of differing opinions on leaving your food under the bed.

Comment: Hello and [welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501). Thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us! If the number 1879026 is not particularly meaningful to you, you can change it ...

Comment: Yes, it’s forbidden. My wife can verify it.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83086/1739

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find in Shulchan Aruch a prohibition to eat in the bedroom.  There is an issue of leaving food under the bed.  But as far as eating in the bedroom it seems perfectly permitted.

However, there is a principle in preparing for Pesach (Mishna Pesachim 1:1), that if a bedroom or cellar has not being frequented the whole year - i.e. one is very careful to not eat at all in such a place, the whole year, one need not do a deep cleaning and checking for Chometz, since one was particular in making sure that this area was free from Chometz the whole year. This is perhaps why many families especially prohibit eating in places other than the kitchen and dining space.

Aside from that, it seems a particular culture - *derech eretz* if you will, of being a mentsch - kings and queens eat in the dining room.  You wouldn't expect Queen Elizabeth II to have her lunch in bed, but rather in a dining room or tea room etc. So as far as behaving like a prince of G-d, it is meaningful to eat in the dining room as kavod and respect to Hashem (we're His children) and the house as a whole.  But this is purely cultural.  People view their bedrooms as their own living spaces (especially children) and certainly have desks and chairs where they study, and eat in those spaces.  Does President Trump have a bite to eat in his bedroom?  Many people drink coffee in their bedrooms.

Comment: I found a picture of H M The Queen taking breakfast in bed [here](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/431430839281760512/visual-search/?x=16&y=11&w=530&h=352).

Comment: I would think this would be a rarity.  Also The Queen is an old lady, and practically it might make sense for her to dine in bed - but that's due to infirmity rather than her status.