# Is food which a child slept over forbidden

Tags: halacha, food, minor-katan-child, yoreh-deah, ruach-rah

The [Halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83090/33665) prohibits sleeping  over food due to ruah rah. Some poskim rule  this doesn’t apply if a gentile sleeps over it. My question is, does this also apply if the person who sleeps over it is a Jewish child under bar/bat mitzvah age?

Comment: It's not a kashrus issue. As for whether it applies to a child's bed, see [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/food-and-drink-left-under-the-bed/) and [here](https://outorah.org/p/27261/).

Comment: Kirk, the link in your first sentence doesn't support it. It quotes various poskim who don't think the issue is sleeping but just being under a bed, who don't think the issue is ruah rah, and who don't say food which was slept over (or placed under a bed) is forbidden after the fact. At best, just ask "According to the poskim who hold of an issue with food under a bed, is a child's bed included?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/food-and-drink-left-under-the-bed/#_ftnref60):
**May food be placed under a crib or bed of a child?**

Some Poskim (Shearim Hametzuyanum Behalacha 33 Kuntrus Acharon 5; Hakashrus 18:29 [p. 436]) rule it is permitted to do so. Other Poskim (Shemiras Haguf Vehanefesh (p. 62) rule one is not to do so.

CYLOR for practical halacha.